# Import Image into tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Ok so I'm currently writing a simple image viewer and I have enough code to be able to view those images, but the only problem is to view the images you want. You have to put them in the same directory as the script and rename them. I want the user to be able to click something like file-open and then import those images. I'm currently using Tkinter as my Gui and PIL for displaying the images. here is my latest code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from Tkinter import Tk, Label, BOTH
from ttk import Frame, Style
import os
import PIL
import Tkinter 

filename = "test.jpg"
filename2 = "test1.jpg"
filename3 = "test2.jpg"
filename4 = "test3.jpg"
basewidth = 300
img = Image.open(filename)
wpercent = (basewidth / float(img.size[0]))
hsize = int((float(img.size[1]) * float(wpercent)))
img = img.resize((basewidth, hsize), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
img.save('resize.jpg')

basewidth = 300
img = Image.open(filename2)
wpercent = (basewidth / float(img.size[0]))
hsize = int((float(img.size[1]) * float(wpercent)))
img = img.resize((basewidth, hsize), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
img.save('resize2.jpg')

basewidth = 300
img = Image.open(filename4)
wpercent = (basewidth / float(img.size[0]))
hsize = int((float(img.size[1]) * float(wpercent)))
img = img.resize((basewidth, hsize), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
img.save('resize4.jpg')
class Example(Frame):



    def __init__(self, parent):
            Frame.__init__(self, parent)   

            self.parent = parent

            self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

            self.parent.title("Picture")
            self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

            Style().configure("TFrame", background="")

            image1 = Image.open("resize.jpg")
            bardejov = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)
            label1 = Label(self, image=bardejov)
            label1.image = bardejov
            label1.place(x=5, y=5)

            image2 = Image.open("resize2.jpg")
            bardejov = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image2)
            label1 = Label(self, image=bardejov)
            label1.image = bardejov
            label1.place(x=5, y=250)

            image3 = Image.open("resize3.jpg")
            bardejov = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image3)
            label1 = Label(self, image=bardejov)
            label1.image = bardejov
            label1.place(x= 350, y=5)

            image3 = Image.open("resize4.jpg")
            bardejov = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image3)
            label1 = Label(self, image=bardejov)
            label1.image = bardejov
            label1.place(x= 350, y=250)

def main():

     root = Tk()
     root.geometry("660x488")
     app = Example(root)
     root.mainloop()  

if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

Comment: What don't you understand about the problem? Are you aware that Tkinter has built-in file dialogs? Or, do you know about it but don't understand how to use it? Or is there something else you don't understand about it?

Comment: I know tkinter has a built in file dialog ive spent all day trying to fiqure it out but i fianlly hit a dead end and posted here i need someone to show me how i would add a file dialog to the define all of the img = what ever goes here to open the file dialog. and then i just dont get how to open it.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go - I do it for one image, you do it for all others similarly

```
import tkFileDialog
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image
import os

root= Tk()

def resizeIt():
    filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
    basewidth = 300
    img = Image.open(filename)
    wpercent = (basewidth / float(img.size[0]))
    hsize = int((float(img.size[1]) * float(wpercent)))
    img = img.resize((basewidth, hsize), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img.save('resize.jpg')
    os.remove(filename) # deletes the original image after you have got the resized image


Button(text='add image', command=resizeIt).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Edit after your question in comment

Yes you can delete a file using the `os` module. First you `import os` in the current namespace and then after you have saved the resized image, you add a line `os.remove(filename)`.
I have done that in the above code.

Comment: something wierd is going on after you select the four images you have to click x to open it how do i add a text to tell the user to do that or do u have a fix by the way thanks

Comment: you can select only one image in one dialog. select a single image from within the file dialog and click 'open'. Thats it. You will get an image by the name resize.jpg in the same location where you have saved this python script

Comment: do i have to have the button four times because i have it repeated four times but all under the def rezimg and then have button(ect) once

Comment: depends on what you want to do. If you have 4 buttons, add 4 new commands like resizeIt1 to resizeIt4 and for each of the methods and also be careful to save each one by a different name. most importantly read some book on python and/or tkinter

Comment: ive gone through learn python the hard way im in the process of learning tkiner

Comment: i got it to work how i wanted but i was wonder if there is a function in python to clear out erase a file contents after it has been opened for exsample one i open 4 images and close it i want it to erase the contents of rezise 4

Comment: no i dont want to delete the old image i want when the python script ends to delete the contents of resize1-4(by delete i mean if you were to open up paint you could start erasing and it would go to a whit background is that posible to do when you close the tkinter window